# How to train multiple times the BigQuery ML model

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

As only 100 iterations are allowed when you create a model, the question is how you retrain the model with new data?

there is a `warm_start` option

them manual says:

> This option is used to retrain a model with new training data, new
>   model options, or both. Unless explicitly overridden, the initial
>   options used to train the model are used for the warm start run. The
>   default value is false.

How to use the `warm_start` options? How do you run multiple training?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run multiple trainings you just set warm_start=true and use the name of the existing model in CREATE MODEL.

Comment: should I use only CREATE MODEL and do not use REPLACE MODEL? Can I use create model from different tables? Can we see how many rows have been used in the training process?